# UUID and collision in java api

Tags: java, database-design, collision, uuid

I'm designing a database and cannot use auto-Inc finally it has 100 billion row(also id).
Is it safe for using U.U.I.D in collision?

Comment: Read about [Random UUID probability of duplicates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates).

Comment: No I'm reading it now.But i think that catch it soon.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't you use auto-inc?

Comment: 100 billion rows? What the heck are you modelling? Primary keys are going to be the least of your worries...

Comment: It stores all of transactions in rows.
maybe i change my code :(

Answer (score 1):

I would use some logic which would intercept PK violation exception and repeat with another UUID